# db2pd equivalent MON functions/views

Tags: db2

I am developing scripts to collect data from DB2 environments. The db2pd tool has a lot of very cool data, but it is a pain to run and collect data compared to running a SQL. The `MON_PKG_CACHE_SUMMARY` provides equivalent data to the `db2pd -tcbstats`.

Does anyone know which DB2 function and/or view can provide equivalent data to `db2pd -edus` please?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [ENV_GET_DB2_EDU_SYSTEM_RESOURCES table function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=erv-env-get-db2-edu-system-resources-return-information-about-database-engine-dispatchable-units).

Comment: I sure missed the ENV* functions in the documentation! Will go over the Knowledge Center more thoroughly. Appreciate the pointer! It certainly looks like the right function.

Comment: Great! Please, mark the answer as accepted then.